# Android: Dynamically Constructing Views Through A Managing Class Error

Tags: java, android, view, constructor, viewgroup

Okay so this is what's going on in my Activity, fig 1---- It's iterate string array and creates buttons. chipContainer is a class (ChipMamma,  shown below, fig 2), with an associated ViewGroup where chips are populated as buttons. That ChipMamma class is supposed to "manage" chips. The two commented-out lines were a previous implementation- with no ChipMamma, just the main activity managing the chips and populating buttons itself (which works). chipButton is a really simple extension of Button (also shown below, fig 3).

**FIGURE 1**

```
    String[] chipAr = {"one","two","three","four", "five","six","seven","eight", "nine","tententententententententententen","eleven","twelve"};
    int count = chipAr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i = i+1){
        chipContainer.newButton(chipAr[i]);
        //chipButton newButton = new chipButton(this, chipAr[i], i+1);
        //((FlowLayout) findViewById(R.id.chipContainer)).addView(newButton);
    }
```

When I use this class as a middle man, everything goes to poop. This is what I can't figure out. And the debug tells me that it can't find the source but I have the source SDK installed...

**Figure 2**

```
public class ChipMamma{ //This was first named "Chip Container"
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<chipButton> chips;
    private ViewGroup vgContainer;
    private int count = 0;

    public ChipMamma(Context context, ViewGroup container){
            this.context = context;
            this.vgContainer = container;
    }
    public void newButton(String chip){
            ChipButton b = new ChipButton(this, this.context, chip, count+1);
            chips.add(b); //This could be problematic if you delete a count
            vgContainer.addView(chips.get(count+1));
            count += 1;
    }
```

This is a chip button class. It's constructor just sets the basic layout params of each chip button (which I would like to move to XML eventually). Basically the debugger gets to the end of the constructor and then gives me the error (even if I remove the last lines, I still get the same error. In fact, the only way I avoid the error is by removing all of the function calls in ChipMamma.newButton).

**Figure 3**

```
public class ChipButton extends Button {
final ChipMamma myMamma;
private Context context;
public ChipButton(ChipMamma theMamma, Context context, String chip, int id) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.myMamma = theMamma;
                this.setId(id); //I've added extra indentation to paramater settings

                this.setPadding(10,  3,  10,  4); //needs to be XML

                //wiggleButton();

                this.setText(chip);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
                    this.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
                } else{
                    this.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
                }

                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                ((Button)this).setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Why can't I add these buttons from inside ChipMamma?

```
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nosite.spendstat/nosite.spendstat.Input}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at nosite.spendstat.ChipMamma.newButton(chipMamma.java:32)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at nosite.spendstat.Input.onCreate(Input.java:212)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
12-01 16:07:58.716: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

You need to instantiate the chips ArrayList before using it -- add

```
chips = new ArrayList<chipButton>()
```

to the ChipMamma constructor.

Then:

In ChipMamma.newButton() you are creating the new Button `b` and putting it into the ArrayList, but then calling addView and retrieving from the ArrayList at an out of bounds index (as ArrayList is 0 based). This causes the ArrayList to return null, and passes null to addView causing the crash.

To resolve, you should get the view out of the ArrayList at index `count` rather than `(count + 1)`, or just pass `b` directly to addView.

Comment: That's true, and it would have produced an error down the road. Thank you. However, I'm getting an error before I even get to that line. I use count+1 as an argument for ChipMamma.ChipButton because I believe View.setId(int) requires a positive (ergo, non-zero?) number. But certain ArrayList IS 0-based.

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer. The problem is the call to addView using count+1. Can you try replacing vgContainer.addView(chips.get(count+1)); with vgContainer.addView(b); ? (inside ChipMamma.newButton())

Comment: Yes I did! and it worked! thank you! I also dropped chips.add() since by using 'b' directly I don't need to use the array list. Obviously I have implemented the array list erroneously and need to reread the doc. I don't think I can mark this as answered until I figure out how to use the arraylist appropriately.

Comment: In fact, even with vgContainer.addView(b), it produces an error because of chips.add(b).

Comment: Aha. You need to new up chips. Add chips = new ArrayList<chipButton>() in the ChipMamma constructor.